# Fifo Flushing Error

Tags: fifo

I am trying this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

int fileFD = 0;
pthread_t Thread_application;
pthread_t Read_Thread;
void * Waiting_Thread(void * arg)
{
    while(1) {
        printf("Created Thread\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}


void * Readtread(void *arg)
{
    char buf[1902] = {0};
    int ret = 0;
    while(1) {
        ret = read(fileFD, buf, 120);
        printf("Read Bytes\n");
    }


}
void main()
{
    int i = 0;

    mkfifo("Desktop/Trail_Programs/ClientFIFO", 0666);
    fileFD = open("Desktop/Trail_Programs/ClientFIFO", O_RDWR);
    pthread_create(&Thread_application, NULL, Waiting_Thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&Read_Thread, NULL, Readtread, NULL);
    sleep(10);

    close(fileFD);
    pthread_kill(Thread_application, 0);
    pthread_kill(Read_Thread, 0);


    system("dd if=Desktop/Trail_Programs/ClientFIFO iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        printf("Main Thread \n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

> Output:    Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> Created Thread
>
> dd: error reading
>   ‘Desktop/Trail_Programs/ClientFIFO’: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable
>
> 0+0 records in
>
> 0+0 records out
>
> 0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000314463 s, 0.0 kB/s
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread
>
> Main Thread

I suppose read is blocking while i am trying to flush the fifo into /dev/null. In my use case opening file with O_NONBLOCK flag and using select to monitor fd, keeps my other processes lagging. please help me with some suggestions

Thanks and Regards,

Ap